Update to Tags in EKS Stack causes an error from Nodegroup "Version and ReleaseVersion updates cannot be combined with other updates"
When trying to update the tags in EKS cluster using cdk, it throws an error
"Version and ReleaseVersion updates cannot be combined with other updates"

This error is produced when updating tags on Nodegroup resource
As a fix I have been referring to the github issue issue
As per their solution, I need to exclude Nodegroup resources from tag update and this needs to be implemented at the construct level which is creating EKS resources instead of applying at Stack/App level.
But this solution requires me to remove original Tagging code which is implemented at Stack level, which will create new changeset causing removal of tag and ultimately triggering the same error.
Is there a way to safely remove the tag from nodegroup resources using cdk without triggering the error
File1.ts
const app = new cdk.App();
       
props.tags.forEach((e) => {
 Tags.of(app).add(e.key, e.value);
});

File2.ts
export class NewEksStack extends Stack {

public blueprint: any;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: Props) {
    super(scope, id, props);


    this.blueprint = new EksBlueprintStack( env properties );
    
    // add tags
    props.tags.forEach((e: any) => {
      console.log('\nTags at EKS construct', e['key'], e['value'] );
      Tags.of(this.blueprint).add(e.key, e.value, {
         excludeResourceTypes: ['AWS::EKS::Nodegroup']
      });
    });

}

export class EksBlueprintStack extends Construct {

...

}


I have tried using Tags.remove at construct level and even tried setting priority field while keeping original Tag code at Stack level, but it doesn't work, maybe because Stack ones overwrites the lower level change.
Can someone please suggest a solution, where I can safely remove these tags from Nodegroup alone using cdk
